# Nginx - using a PHP file for errors 404, 403, 500, etc

Tags: nginx

I would like to have the same error pages set up in the various sites hosted on my server. In other words, every `server` block should have the same error settings:

```
    error_page 404 403 /404.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.php;
    location = /404.php { root /home/main; allow all; }
    location = /50x.php { root /home/main; }
```

Then, inside the PHP of each error page, I check for `$_REQUEST['HTTP_HOST']` and show the message accordingly. This is nice and easy to manage the error messages of all websites, where the design for this doesn't need to change much.

Issue: this works for HTML files and URLs without any specific extension. But if the non-existent URL (i.e, one which should produce a 404) contains a .file extension, it doesn't work.

example.com/nonexistent-folder/    ---> This works, shows the 404.php content
example.com/nonexistent.gif        ---> This doesn't work

The second URL shows in Chrome as ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

A CURL header check probably sheds some light:

```
        curl -I https://example.com/nonexistent.gif
        HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
        Server: nginx
        Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2017 18:19:48 GMT
        Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
        Content-Length: 1840
        Connection: keep-alive
```

The Content-type is PHP. Is this an issue? For a GIF non-existent file, does the Content-type need to be GIF? If not, what's causing this `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` in browsers?

Comment: Just to check, I forced a `header` in the 404.php of GIF in case the `REQUEST_URI` of the current request contained GIF. It doesn't work in this case at all as the PHP then doesn't execute as PHP.

Comment: Did you forget to set the `Content-Type:` in your PHP script?

Comment: What should I set it to?

Comment: Probably `text/html` or something along those lines. You are serving a 404 page, right?

Comment: Making the header text/html just before the `echo $html; ` makes the file download, instead of executing and showing in the browser. Note that the `$html` is the variable that captures the contents of the 404 page, with variables that capture the various domains (logo, title, fonts, etc).